# Multiline Comment Workarounds?

Tags: r, comments, r-faq

I (sort of) already know the answer to this question.  But I figured it is one that gets asked so frequently on the R Users list, that there should be one solid good answer.  **To the best of my knowledge there is no multiline comment functionality in R.  So, does anyone have any good workarounds?**

While quite a bit of work in R usually involves interactive sessions (which casts doubt on the need for multiline comments), there are times when I've had to send scripts to colleagues and classmates, much of which involves nontrivial blocks of code.  And for people coming from other languages it is a fairly natural question.

In the past I've used quotes. Since strings support linebreaks, running an R script with

```
"
Here's my multiline comment.

"
a <- 10
rocknroll.lm <- lm(blah blah blah)
 ...
```

works fine.  Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: My best suggestion would be to write a macro (or plugin in case you use something like Sublime Text 2) and assign a keybinding such that selected text (i.e. comments) get a # in the front once you hit the appropriate key bindings.

Comment: If you haven't tried Rstudio I would definitely recommend it. I think you can easily comment/uncomment several lines.

Comment: Notepad++ recognises R as a language and allows block commenting of code.

Comment: Ctrl+Q in Notepad++, Ctrl+Shift+C in RStudio

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This does come up on the mailing list fairly regularly, see [for example this recent thread on r-help](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/156893).  The consensus answer usually is the one shown above: that given that the language has no direct support, you have to either

- work with an editor that has region-to-comment commands, and most advanced R editors do
- use the `if (FALSE)` constructs suggested earlier but note that it still requires complete parsing and must hence be syntactically correct

Comment: Thanks.  Would you mind expanding a bit on whether or not there are any prospects for multiline comments, whether it is a philosophical thing, etc.?

Comment: I think it is due to the nature of the parser, and the fact that R is also an interactive environment (i.e.: command-line) rather than mostly a file-based interpreter where multi-line comments would be more common.  So not philosophical -- it has grown this way.

Comment: Now that R has compiled code, do we think multi-line comments are going to make an appearance?

Comment: No, as the underlying parser has not changed.

Comment: Just posted an answer that doesn't require correct syntax, although it is more for here-string type documenting and commenting than simple code-block enable/disable toggle.

Answer (score 119):

Most of the editors take some kind of shortcut to comment out blocks of code.  The default editors use something like command or control and single quote to comment out selected lines of code.  In RStudio it's <kbd>Command</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.  Check in your editor.

It's still commenting line by line, but they also uncomment selected lines as well.  For the Mac RGUI it's command-option ' (I'm imagining windows is control option).  For Rstudio it's just <kbd>Command</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> again.

These shortcuts will likely change over time as editors get updated and different software becomes the most popular R editors. You'll have to look it up for whatever software you have.

Comment: Yep, this is a super-handy feature. In Emacs, just highlight the area-to-be commented out, and type `C-x r t` followed by the characters you'd like to add (something like `"## "`). To indent a code block for SO, do the same thing, but replace those last three characters with four spaces!

Comment: In Emacs you can also use `M-x comment-region`. Didn't know about `C-x r`, thanks!

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+C toggles commenting of the selection under eclipse/StatET.

Comment: CTRL + D can be used in Kate (KDE Advanced Text Editor) to toggle block comments.

Comment: @John -- ok, I found it out by hacking madly :-).  To add a "#" to every line, select the block and type "CMD-'" . To remove a "#" from every line, select the block and type "CMD-OPT-' " .

Comment: Don't understand, for me ctrl+shift+C on a commented section just adds a second set of #'s in front of code

Comment: @Garglesoap I had the same problem. It's because RStudio comments or uncomments the entire block based on whether the first selected line has a # or not. My first line did not have # so the whole selection got an extra # per line. The rest of the selection already had a # so ended up with # #.

Comment: @Garglesoap not only will it double comment  if the first selected line doesn't have a #. If any line in the block doesn't have a # it will add the second # to the whole block. If they all begin with # then ctrl+shift+C removes the #. I had this problem too.

Answer (score 80):

You can do this easily in [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/source):

select the code and click <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
to comment/uncomment code.

Answer (score 75):

A sort of block comment uses an if statement:

```
if(FALSE) {
  all your code
}
```

It works, but I almost always use the block comment options of my editors (RStudio, Kate, Kwrite).

Answer (score 45):

A neat trick for RStudio I've just discovered is to use `#'` as this creates an self-expanding comment section (when you return to new line from such a line or insert new lines into such a section it is automatically comment).

Comment: This is neat! Great one. Someone should combine this answer with the one provided by @Salvador because these can be used in different cases.

Answer (score 37):

Wrap it in an unused function:

```
.f = function() {

## unwanted code here:

}
```

Answer (score 21):

[Update] Based on comments.

```
# An empty function for Comments
Comment <- function(`@Comments`) {invisible()}

#### Comments ####
Comment( `

  # Put anything in here except back-ticks.

  api_idea <- function() {
    return TRUE
  }

  # Just to show api_idea isn't really there...
  print( api_idea )

`)
####

#### Code. ####
foo <- function() {
  print( "The above did not evaluate!")
}
foo()
```

---

[Original Answer]

Here's another way...  check out the pic at the bottom.  Cut and paste the code block into RStudio.

Multiline comments that make using an IDE *more* effective are a "Good Thing", most IDEs or simple editors don't have highlighting of text within simple commented -out blocks; though some authors have taken the time to ensure parsing within here-strings.  With R we don't have multi-line comments or here-strings either, but using invisible expressions in RStudio gives all that goodness.

As long as there aren't any backticks in the section desired to be used for a multiline comments, here-strings, or non-executed comment blocks then this might be something worth-while.

```
#### Intro Notes & Comments ####
invisible( expression( `
{ <= put the brace here to reset the auto indenting...

  Base <- function()
  {      <^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Use the function as a header and nesting marker for the comments
         that show up in the jump-menu.
         --->8---
  }

  External <- function()
  {
    If we used a function similar to:
      api_idea <- function() {

        some_api_example <- function( nested ) {
          stopifnot( some required check here )
        }

        print("Cut and paste this into RStudio to see the code-chunk quick-jump structure.")
        return converted object
      }

    #### Code. ####
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <= Notice that this comment section isnt in the jump menu!
                                  Putting an apostrophe in isn't causes RStudio to parse as text
                                  and needs to be matched prior to nested structure working again.
    api_idea2 <- function() {

    } # That isn't in the jump-menu, but the one below is...

    api_idea3 <- function() {

    }

  }

    # Just to show api_idea isn't really there...
    print( api_idea )
    }`) )
####

#### Code. ####
foo <- function() {
  print( "The above did not evaluate and cause an error!")
}

foo()

## [1] "The above did not evaluate and cause an error!"
```

And here's the pic...

[image: Structured Comments]

Comment: I think you can define `comment=function(z){invisible(expression(z))}` which might help people understand what the heck is going on!

Comment: Perhaps even better, `Comments<-function(\`@Comments\`)rm(\`@Comments\`)`.  Since comment is already a valid function.

Comment: Do you need to actually do anything with the arg? `Comments=function(x){}` will work for where `x` is a multiline expression delimited by backquote. It won't try to evaluate it...

Comment: Source with echo shows NULL when the empty braces do not contain invisible()

Comment: But with ``Comment <- function(`@Comments`) {invisible()}``, if the comment is too long, you get an error: `variable names are limited to 10000 bytes`

Answer (score 13):

I can think of two options. The first option is to use an editor that allows to block comment and uncomment (eg. Eclipse). The second option is to use an if statement. But that will only allow you to 'comment' correct R syntax.  Hence a good editor is the prefered workaround.

```
if(FALSE){
     #everything in this case is not executed

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to modify this so that if FALSE were changed to TRUE it would run multiple lines of code within the curly brackets instead of just the last one?

Answer (score 10):

If find it incredible that any language would not cater for this.

This is probably the cleanest workaround:

```
anything="
first comment line
second comment line
"
```

Comment: Works fine unless you want quotes in your comment ;)

Answer (score 7):

Apart from using the overkilled way to comment multi-line codes just by installing RStudio, you can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/%E2%80%8E) as it supports the syntax highlighting of R

(Select multi-lines) -> Edit -> Comment/Uncomment -> Toggle Block Comment

Note that you need to save the code as a .R source first (highlighted in red)

[image: Note that you need to save the code as a .R source first (highlighted in red)]

Answer (score 2):

I use vim to edit the R script.

Let's say the R script is test.R, containing say "Line 1", "Line 2", and "Line 3" on 3 separate lines.

I open test.R on the command line with Vim by typing "vim test.R".
Then I go to the 1st line I want to comment out, type "Control-V", down arrow to the last line I want to comment out, type a capital I i.e. "I" for insert, type "# ", and then hit the Escape key to add "# " to every line that I selected by arrowing down. Save the file in Vim and then exit Vim by typing ":wq". Changes should show up in Rstudio.

To delete the comments in Vim, start at the first line on top of the character "#" you want to delete, again do "Control-V", and arrow down to the last line you want to delete a "#" from. Then type "dd". The "#" signs should be deleted.

There's seconds-worth of lag time between when changes to test.R in Vim are reflected in Rstudio.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is a workaround, by using package [ARTofR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ARTofR/index.html) or [bannerCommenter](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bannerCommenter/index.html)

Examples here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use RStudio or Emacs and always use the editor shortcuts available to comment regions. If this is not a possibility then you could use Paul's answer but this only works if your code is syntactically correct.

Here is another dirty way I came up with, wrap it in `scan()` and remove the result. It does store the comment in memory for a short while so it will probably not work with very large comments. Best still is to just put `#` signs in front of every line (possibly with editor shortcuts).

```
foo <- scan(what="character")
These are comments
These are still comments
Can also be code:
x <- 1:10
One line must be blank

rm(foo)
```

Comment: Even dirtier variation.  Define `"#" <- function() invisible(scan(what = character()))` then start your comment block with `"#"()`.

Comment: The previous answer should really have backticks rather than quotes (though it works in either case), but I'll be darned if I can figure out how to get backticks into a code block inside a comment.

Comment: Richie, nice suggestion, but slashes will generate error messages:Error: unexpected '/' in:
"`#`(  # start of comment
http:/"

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this at talkstats.com in posts 94, 101 & 103 found in the thread: [Share Your Code](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/18603-Share-your-functions-amp-code/page3).  As others have said Rstudio may be a better way to go.  I store these functions in my .Rprofile and actually use them a but to automatically block out lines of code quickly.

Not quite as nice as you were hoping for but may be an approach.

Answer (score 0):

In [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) an easy way to do this is to write your comment and once you have used CTRL + Shift + C to comment your line of code, then use CTRL + SHIFT + / to reflow you comment onto multiple lines for ease of reading.

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio you can use a pound sign and quote like this:

```
#' This is a comment
```

Now, every time you hit return you don't need to add the #', RStudio will automatically put that in for you.

Incidentally, for adding parameters and items that are returned, for standardization if you type an @ symbol inside those comment strings, RStudio will automatically show you a list of codes associated with those comment parameters:

```
#' @param tracker_df Dataframe of limit names and limits
#' @param invoice_data Dataframe of invoice data
#' @return return_list List of scores for each limit and rejected invoice rows
```

Comment: Aren't `#'` and `@` actually package _roxygen2_ syntax?