# R: Comment out block of code

Tags: r, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: Multiline Comment Workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231195/r-multiline-comment-workarounds)

I want to comment out several lines of code in R. Is there any way of doing it without having to put a # before each line - sort of like `/* blocked out code */` in SAS?