# How do I discern between comments and commented-out code in R?

Tags: r

I am someone who tries my best to make my code reproducible and understandable.  So I took the idea "make useful comments" and "comment every line of code".
Is there another way to comment code besides this mess that like the previous post mentioned:

Here is a simulated reproducible using a simple lines of code and [Tidyverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidyverse).  For this example please pretend that the library (package) is the most complicated code you have seen.

```
# this a comment
## this is a tabbed comment
library(tidyverse) # this is an inline comment
```

But what if you commented that out.

```
# this a comment
library(ggplot2) # this is an inline comment
# library(tidyverse) This is commented code
```

Now you have something that is hard to understand.  Which is the comment and which is the code?

I wish there was a way in the syntax to add another character to help distinguish my comments and comment out code.

Comment: P.S. I asking because when I did a search for the answer then on programming I found that question appeared to have been never properly answered but was pushed to other community: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481879/r-managing-comments-versus-commented-out-code . I am hoping that things have changed in the last 7 years that basic questions are finally acceptable on stack overflow.
I found myself thinking about this after 4 years of doing R.

Comment: Do either of the suggested answers resolve your question ... ?

Comment: Yes, I been really busy with helping with local elections since September.  @BenBolker I really appreciated both answer as they both answer different aspects of the problem.  Ben you answered how to comment code properly when there already a comment exists.  While Jackson answer better general comment practices.  Thank you both for your help. :)

Comment: *"this a comment"* is missing a [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verb#Noun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with many the answers on the link you referenced [Commenting R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481879/r-managing-comments-versus-commented-out-code).  Commenting in R starts with a # and block comments are not supported.

Having said that, you could make your own scheme.  As long as your comment line starts with a `#`, you can follow it with anything

You could make your own schema to visually allow you to tell where commented code is vs actual comments

If you used something like:

```
####### This is an actual comment
```

or

```
##<---- Comment This is also a comment ---->
```

or

```
######################
## Fancy comment for the next series of code lines
## More comements
## More verbose comments
######################
```

or like Roxygen2 comments from the above liniked comment.  Roxygen2 [Roxygen2 documentation with schema for comments](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html) uses a predefined schema of `#'`:

```
#' roxygen2 Comments
#' roxygen2 Comments2
```

You could visually see the difference.  Additionally, you could search for `##` or `#'` to find actual comments and search for `#`  (hash with a space) to find commented code.

Answer (score 1):

This is in danger of getting opinion-based answers, but I'll try to give an objective answer.

- Without *serious* hacking, you won't be able to change the parser to add an additional comment character
- when I have commented-out lines with comments, I usually add an additional set of comment characters:

```
# library(tidyverse) ## This is commented code
```

This way if I uncomment the line, the comment stays commented.

- some programming interfaces (such as Emacs) distinguish between the meanings/default indentation of different numbers of hash characters: single hash (`#`) gets indented to a standard comment depth, double (`##`) gets indented to the current code indentation level, and three or more (`###`) gets set to the beginning of the line.  You could adopt a convention for yourself similar to this.  (Similarly, *anything* you include after a hash is ignored, so you could decide for yourself that `#* ...` represented a "real" character)
- some people consider it bad practice, but as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107695/r-comment-out-block-of-code) if you delimit a code block with `if (FALSE) { ... }`, it won't get executed (although it does need to be syntactically valid code, which isn't required for commented material