# Temporarily disable a series of commands in R script during debugging

Tags: r

I am trying to debug a lengthy script in R. Suppose I want to block out a long for-loop. Besides typing in pound-symbols ("#") before each line of code in the for-loop, or besides manually selecting which lines of code to run, is there another way to temporarily disable an entire for-loop (or a lengthy series of code) from running?

For a simple example, I want to do something like the following:

```
code to be run;

#[code to be disabled];
#for(i in 1:5){;
series of ~100 commands in for-loop;
};

other code to be run;
```

I want to be able to put a single "#" symbol at the front of the for-loop and have it disable the entire loop, but instead, I have to put a "#" symbol in each line of the lengthy for-loop. Is something like this possible?

The problem is magnified when there are a large number of lengthy for-loops that need to be temporarily disabled. Simply putting a "#" symbol next to all of these lines proves unwieldy, as does individually selecting which lines to run.

Comment: Use an `if(FALSE){}` construction, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231195/multiline-comment-workarounds).

Comment: Also, you don't need semi-colons on the ends of your lines.

Comment: If you're using RStudio, you have a nice keyboard shortcut which makes it easy to put a large portion of code in comment. See the Code menu

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using RStudio, but maybe issues such as this should move me toward using it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use the following:

```
if (FALSE){

    #code I don't want to run

}
```

Does this help?