# How can I add a hashtag # sign to many lines in r command?

Tags: r

I  want to add  hashtag  # sign before   many lines in r. How can I do it using a shortcut key?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231195/multiline-comment-workarounds)

Comment: If you're using RStudio, highlight the text, then "Ctrl+Shft+C"

Comment: .. command/shift/c on a mac

Comment: It's called a "comment character", not a "hashtag".

Comment: @PierreLafortune  It is already in that link

Answer (score 20):

R Studio: Highlight the text and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to comment multiple lines.

Comment: Is there someway to do the opposite action, to remove the highlight?

Comment: @Arduin select the lines that have comment # on, and `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `C` again is to do the opposite action (uncomment)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is slightly different to the question asked but after multiple failed searches on stackoverflow for a solution to my question, all which ended up on this page, I thought I would add this for anyone in a similar situation. I was looking for a quick way (purely for aesthetic commenting reasons) to add a line of #### across a R script, rather than holding down the <kbd>#</kbd> button, I came across the `bannerCommenter` package which I think is really useful. It also has other formats.

```
    library(bannerCommenter)
    #run the following command which saves the comment to clipboard
    #then just paste on next line of script
    banner("Section 1:", "Data input and initialization", emph = TRUE) 

    ###########################################################################
    ###########################################################################
    ###                                                                     ###
    ###                              SECTION 1:                             ###
    ###                 DATA INPUT AND INITIALIZATION                       ###
    ###                                                                     ###
    ###########################################################################
    ###########################################################################
```

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633920/dynamic-rstudio-code-snippet

Answer (score 1):

rather than multiple "#", i prefer to use ' (apostrof)  between lines to disable it. for example:

```
'dim(train);dim(test)
names(train)
names(test)
str(train)
str(test)'
```

in R console, 5 lines above will return:

```
> 'dim(train);dim(test)
+ names(train)
+ names(test)
+ str(train)
+ str(test)'
[1] "dim(train);dim(test)\nnames(train)\nnames(test)\nstr(train)\nstr(test)"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way of doing this!!!
If you are using a mouse press the scroll button (don't scroll it) over the edge of the starting of line. Many signs like "|" would be made. Now just press 'shift + #' to comment multiple lines or even a paragraph in python.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC (R Studio): Highlight the text and use COMMAND+SHIFT+C to comment multiple lines. The same is for removing comment.

Answer (score -1):

In base R (on a Mac), highlight multiple rows and use: `command` + `'`.