# "If (FALSE)" with no condition explicitly stated

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean

I've received some code from someone who apparently likes to use the following syntax:

```
if(FALSE) {
    opt <- list("cores" = 1, "degradation" = TRUE, "test" = TRUE)
}
```

What does this mean? If what is `FALSE`? The last condition evaluated? I'm confused

Comment: This could be a trick to comment out a whole section of code without having to use #, quite practical when you have many lines, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Waldi, please post as answer.  (An advantage of commenting out code sections in this way is that it still gets syntax-highlighted as regular code; that can also be a disadvantage because it makes it harder to distinguish as a comment block.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one of the available techniques [to comment out multiple lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231195/multiline-comment-workarounds).

- advantages :

  - you don't need to use # for every line
  - as pointed out by @Ben Bolker, code syntax highlighting is still active so that you know that you can anytime switch it on by using `if (T)` instead of `if (F)`
- disadvantage :

  - you don't see as clearly as with # what is commented out

Answer (score 3):

> If what is `FALSE`?

`FALSE` itself. `FALSE` is a logical value. And the syntax for `if` is

```
if (condition) …
```

That “condition” can be *any* expression that evaluates to something that R can interpret as a logical value. `FALSE` is such an expression. So `if (FALSE)` is basically the same as writing `if (a condition that’s never true)`.

So this construct is quite meaningless: the whole `if` block will always be skipped, you might as well remove it. As explained in the other answer, some people use this construct to easily disable larger chunks of code. I don’t recommend this practice: code that’s never evaluated is called [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code), and it’s clutter and thus incurs [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) (all these are effectively terms that say that it decreases the overall code quality).