# Exclude selected text in R (Rstudio)

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to select part of my R script and "exclude" it by inserting # at the beginning of each line. (I don't know what's the term for this)

Sample code:

```
df <- 
   data.frame(Numbers = 1:26,
              Letters = letters) 

df
```

What I would like to do:

```
#df <- 
#   data.frame(Numbers = 1:26,
#              Letters = letters) 

#df
```

Is there a shortcut to do this other than inserting the #'s manually?

Comment: This is called “commenting out” code. In RStudio on Windows the default shortcut is Ctrl-Shift-C.

Comment: See here for multiple options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231195/multiline-comment-workarounds

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Select line and Ctrl+Shift+c

Answer (score 2):

## Ctrl+ Shift + C

> If you use RStudio, you can use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Shift + C (Command + Shift + C on macOS) to comment out a line of text.

[Source](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/comments.html)